# What are the best practice ways of handling many arguments and/or longer argument names in a function definition?

Tags: python, styles, coding-style

what is the best practice for writing functions if many arguments are involved or if some arguments are long? I know stylistically, no line of code should exceed 80 or so characters, including indentations.

From a style-perspective, is it generally ok to go into the second or third line of the function definition? For example.

```
def myFunction(arg1, arg2, arg3, longerArg1,
               longerArg2, longerArg3):
```

What if I "pack" similar arguments into arrays before calling the function, then call the function. Then within the function, "unpack" the array into variables and use accordingly. For example, we have several arguments containing various quantities.

```
def myFunction(multiArg, longArgs):
    var1, var2, var3 = multiArg[0], multiArg[1], multiArg[2]
    longVar1 = longArgs[0]
    longVar2 = longArgs[1]
    longVar3 = longArgs[2]

arg1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
arg2 = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
arg3 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
longerArg1 = "Hello"
longerArg2 = 4.6
longerArg3 = "Some Labels"

multiArg = [arg1, arg2, arg3]
longArgs = [longerArg1, longerArg2, longerArg3]

myFunction(multiArg, longArgs)
```

While this will work as intended, but I would like to write cleaner and more readable code. What's the proper style-way of handling these function definitions?

For my specific application, I'm trying to generate several plots (`matplotlib`), where each plot involves several data parameters, titles, xLabels, yLabels, etc. This alone will amount to 5+ different arguments with variable names containing varying amounts of characters. Writing out the function definition line (`def myFunction()`) with all the arguments will definitely exceed the standard 80 characters.

Comment: As you only seem to be using positional parameters you could consider using the convention *def myFunction(*args)* then, within the function unpack the *args* tuple to access the parameters you actually need. Admittedly not very readable but it does keep the function declaration short

Answer (score 0):

Stylistically speaking, the proposed solution [is offered in pep 8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#indentation) in accordance with your first solution.